# Include hex key validation in signup process

Tags: node.js, express, hex, passport.js, passport-local

I am following a tutorial to create a web app to do user authentication (signup/login): https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

I was wondering how I could add validation to the signup part. Let me clarify. I will be selling a product to users. People who buy the product will receive a 128-bit HEX key with the product so that they can register it.

I have a list of, let's say, 1000 of those keys that I generated. How can I ensure that the user registering is inputting a valid key? (a previously generated one) I am pretty sure I would have to put those keys in a database, but what next?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Store the key reference along with the user(since they bought your product I am assuming you have their details previously) in a table or a document or any other. So that you can validate that the key is valid and allowed for that user in a single lookup. It has nothing to do with the tutorial mentioned. HEX key can be anything a coupon for example.

Cheers.